Is there a way to add Image using "saveIncremental" without invalidating previous signature
I'm currently trying to enable multiple users to sign PDF using Apache PDFBox.
My goal is to add images to a PDF incrementally without invalidating previous signatures. So far, I have successfully used form fields(text fields with signature fields) with lock dictionaries to continue saving using saveIncremental, which works fine. However, I want to use images instead of form fields.
I tried to insert images in following ways

Using Form Fields:
I used PDbutton form fields and updated their widgets to set images as appearances. This worked fine until the image size is same and fits within the button field itself. But the image width is greater than button field, In such cases, the image gets squashed into the original field size (in screenshot).
Referenced from :  https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/issues/18
squashed image
Expectation: I was expecting to update the button field dimensions to fit the image without invalidating the previous signature. However, resizing the button field seems to invalidate the signature.
Using Annotations:

I tried using annotations to save images (reference), which gives full control over the image dimensions. However, I'm not sure if these annotations are saved as part of the signature revision. Also, I'm concerned that these annotations can be edited or deleted after signing, which is not desirable.
Expectation: I want a way to ensure that annotations are locked and cannot be edited or deleted after signing, maintaining the integrity of the previous signatures.
=====================================================================
Questions:
**Is there some other way to achieve this?
**I'm currently using PDFBox 2.0.28, but I'm open to switching to a different library if it supports this use case.
Or is the best solution to do this is to use form fields(text, checkbox, listfield ...) and use button fields when images that has fixed size?

I'm afraid you're out of luck: changing the dimensions of a field is not considered a form fill-in, so it is disallowed in signed documents. And you can only lock fields, not other annotations. So if you can add arbitrary annotations, others also can change it remove them. If you sign the document again after your changes, though, you have the option to decrease the MDP level with that signature to forbid changes to annotations.

My goal is to add images to a PDF incrementally
Are those images of signatures or different kind of images? Which each image do you add a signature or not?

@Lonzak I do give visual appearance to signature fields, but i would also like to add other images to PDF

@mkl Thanks for the explanation. Curious about a few things though.

When I tried to change the form field properties and fit the image, I was expecting it to invalidate the previous signature, but it didn't. However, the signature panel says "there were subsequent changes to the PDF," as shown in the image: image link. Is this behavior expected?



When you mention decreasing the MDP level, are you referring to using FieldMDP? Does that mean it won't allow editing annotations?


"When I tried to change the form field properties and fit the image, I was expecting it to invalidate the previous signature, but it didn't. However, the signature panel says "there were subsequent changes to the PDF," as shown in the image. Is this behavior expected?" - What to report about changes after signatures, is not specified independently, so what to expect here, is vague and subjective. In my opinion, if I have a PDF validation report, I want to know what changes there were after the signatures, even allowed ones, so for me such information in the signature panel are expected.

"When you mention decreasing the MDP level, are you referring to using FieldMDP? Does that mean it won't allow editing annotations?" - I'm referring to the new feature added to FieldMDP in PDF 2.0 (previously already available as part of an Adobe developer extension to PDF 1.7), the P entry in the signature field lock dictionary. It allows decreasing access permissions, e.g. from 3 (form fill-in + annotation changes) to 2 (only form fill-in) which would fix your annotation additions (or at least invalidate that final signature if ignored).

@mkl "if I have a PDF validation report, I want to know what changes there were after the signatures, even allowed ones, so for me such information in the signature panel are expected" ---- Thanks for the clarification. I understand your point about reporting changes after signatures.
However, I wanted to understand why adjusting the field properties didn't invalidate the previous signature, as I thought this action is not one of the allowed modifications after signing the PDF. Could you shed some light on this behavior?

Well, unfortunately it is not really well-defined what is allowed and what is disallowed: e.g. the specification only says "form fill-in is allowed" but does not clarify what that means on the level of post objects. Theoretically form fill-in wouldn't need to include changing of button appearances at all. But Adobe once chose to miss-use buttons as "image field", so they in their validator allowed that nonetheless. Which changes in a button exactly they allow, depends on what they needed for their customers and on the other hand what is explored in forgery.

@mkl Thanks for the explanation. I think using annotations and restriction using MDP sounds like good idea. Thanks!!
